# Loading Text File into Div Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, text, hyperlink

I created this script:

```
  <script>function txtload () {$(".divbody").load("maintxt/information1.txt");}</script>
```

I am using links like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ChangeImage(), txtload ()">Information 1</a>
```

I need to change the script to create multiple href's loading different text for each link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ChangeImage(), txtload ()">Information 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ChangeImage(), txtload ()">Information 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ChangeImage(), txtload ()">Information 3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ChangeImage(), txtload ()">Information 4</a>
```

Can you help? I tried removing the "" from the script and placing it in the href itself...don't have any idea what I'm doing...

Think this should work. Please give me your input:

```
<script>function txtload () {$(".divbody").load("maintxt/" + filename);}</script>

<a href="#" onclick="ChangeImage(), txtload ("information1.txt")">Information 1</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a parameter

```
<script>
    function txtload ( url ) {
        $(".divbody").load( url );
    }
</script>
```

And then in your html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="txtload('url to your text file')">Information 1</a>
```

Or if you really want it in your href use:

```
<a href="your url" onclick="txtload(this.href); return false;">Information 1</a>
```

In your code is also a function `ChangeImage` which you haven't explained anywhere. I just ignored it in my example.

Another way which is actually a little nicer is this script:

```
$("a.some_class_for_these_links").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".divbody").load( this.href );
});
```

And then this html

```
<a href="your url" class="some_class_for_these_links">Information 1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use jQuery there is no point in using inline script with `onclick`;

Give the links a common class and you can use the `href` to assign the file you want loaded.

```
<a href="maintxt/information1.txt" class="load_link">Information 1</a>
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$(function(){

   $('.load_link').click(function(){
       ChangeImage();
       /* "this" is actual link clicked*/
       $(".divbody").load(this.href);
        /* prevent browser opening new page*/
        return false;

  })
})
```

If user has javascript disabled they will still be able to access the data since it is in `href` and click on link will allow them to view text file . So will search engine bots